# Discord.py | How to only check for author message?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am creating a bot that verifies if a member is in our school or not. for some reason, after entering a student number, the bot asks to enter it again instead of sending an email

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
await member.send("You have joined the unofficial (school) discord server! To access the rest of the server you must "
                  "confirm you are from (our school).")
sent_email = False
confirmation_key = generate_key()
while not sent_email:
    await member.send('What is your student number? ')
    response = await client.wait_for('message')
    student_number = response.content
    if student_number.isalpha() or student_number.isalnum():
        await member.send("Please Enter Your Student Number!")
    elif student_number.isnumeric():
        send_mail(student_number, confirmation_key)
        sent_email = True
        await member.send(f'Sending Confirmation Email...')
```

Any answers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`student_number.isalnum()` will always return `True` if `student_number` only contains numbers, so you won't ever reach the `elif` case.

It may make more sense to reorganize your code a bit:

```
if student_number.isnumeric():
        send_mail(student_number, confirmation_key)
        sent_email = True
        await member.send(f'Sending Confirmation Email...')
else:
        await member.send("Please Enter Your Student Number!")
```

To my understanding you are only interested in two scenarios:

1. The student number is formatted correctly (only has numbers)
2. The student number is formatted incorrectly

This way you handle both cases and get rid of the tricky logic with `isalnum()`.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much. This definitely simplifies it. I was making it tricky for no reason. Again thank you so much, you are awesome!